# SQL Server 2008 Query to pull the max account date opened

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have the table as below,
        i would like to find the max(account_opened_date), if there is null date is existing, i have to show null values.

**Scenario1**

**Table1**

```
CLIENTID            ACCOUNTID           ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE
11562               3880                07/05/2012
11562               3884                08/05/2012
11562               3885                09/06/2012
11562               3886                10/06/2012
11562               3881                NULL
11562               3882                NULL
```

the results are as below.

```
CLIENTID            ACCOUNTID           ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE  
11562               3882                NULL
```

in the above scenario, i have to take null because, there is null values existing in account opened dates

**Scenario2**

**Table1**

```
CLIENTID            ACCOUNTID           ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE  
11563               3880                07/05/2012
11563               3884                08/05/2012
11563               3885                09/06/2012
11563               3886                10/06/2012
11563               3881                11/10/2011
11563               3882                10/22/2012
```

The results ARE AS below.

```
CLIENTID            ACCOUNTID           ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE
11563               3882                10/22/2012
```

in the above scenario, i have to take 10/22/2012 because, there is no null values existing in account opened dates
PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CLIENTID, ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by clientid 
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE IS NULL THEN '12/31/9999' 
                      ELSE ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE END DESC) opened_date_rank
FROM dbo.Table1
) v WHERE opened_date_rank = 1
```

Example:

```
declare @table table (clientid int, accountid int, opened_date date)
insert into @table 
select 11562, 3880, '07/05/2012' UNION ALL
select 11562,3884, '08/05/2012' UNION ALL
select 11562,3882, null UNION ALL
select 11563,3880, '07/05/2012' UNION ALL
select 11563,3884, '08/05/2012' UNION ALL
select 11563,3882,'10/22/2012'



SELECT * FROM (
SELECT clientid, accountid, opened_date, 
row_number() over (partition by clientid 
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN opened_date IS NULL THEN '12/31/9999' 
                      ELSE opened_date END DESC) opened_date_rank
FROM @table
) v where opened_date_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select `TOP 1` to get one record and `ORDER BY CASE` for your "null-first" requirement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CLIENTID, ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE
FROM dbo.Table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
  , ACCOUNT_OPENED_DATE DESC
  , ACCOUNTID DESC
```

- Scenario 1 fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7906/1/0
- Scenario 2 fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/752db/1/0

Comment: if there are more than one `clientid` this will not work (check scenario1 and scenario2)

Comment: In what way? `TOP 1` will always return one record which is what OP wants.

Comment: ok i thought he was trying to query both scenarios in one query